# Energy using Hanning window

Tags: window

I am a newbie in signal processing. I am testing the Hanning window on a signal. Obviously doing this window also means cut some energy of the signal, and when I do the DFT, the 0 frequency is not equivalent anymore to the average of the time history. Do you usually solve in some way this problem?
Can someone suggest papers or books where noise-reducing strategies for the FT of a signal are investigated? I just don't know how to start, an online search didn't give me more than basic definition (so please don't send me the Wikipedia definition of the tapering window)

Best

Comment: Hm, I find difficult to relate Hanning window, the DC frequency, and noise reduction in the frequency domain. What kind of signals are you dealing with?

Comment: In a nutshell, you must normalize the energy by the energy of the window. In case of simple magnitude, this means dividing by the sum of window samples.
[This publication](https://holometer.fnal.gov/GH_FFT.pdf) has great explainations.

Comment: Excellent reference, thank you for reminding me it is in my "to read in a serious manner" list for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are talking about the Hann window, after [Julius von Hann, and Blackman & Tukey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_von_Hann#Hann_window). Of course, a non-constant window may induce energy variations, either used as a weighted average, or a convolutional filter. This can be compensated in several ways:

- by normalizing the window amplitudes
- by separating tipme-portions, or signal components, like removing the mean or low-frequencies before doing the processing
- by modelling the signal and applying model-based corrections.

More would be needed on your signal to provide more precise answers. R. Lyons on a diagram on page xviii of his book [Understanding Digital Signal Processing](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT3205/Documents/UnderstandingDigitalSignalProcessing.pdf) highlights the importance of windows.